# What is difference between google cloud functions and web services running on virtual machine on google cloud?

Tags: function, rest, service, server, cloud

I want to access mysql database from all plateforms including mobile,desktop and web apps.
I thought that running a vm on cloud with nodejs and apache will fullfil my requirements. This vm will receive request from all apps and get data from mysql server  and respond with a json object irrespective of plateform.
But I got to know that cloud functions can do the same thing. ie pooling data from mysql server and respond with json object.

1. Can you please help me to understand the difference b/w them?
2. Which will be best choice, cloud functons or running web services on vm?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Google Cloud Function is a serverless way of running your code on the cloud. For ref: https://logz.io/blog/serverless-guide/
I recommend you explore more on serverless architecture: https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-serverless-architecture

One main advantage of using serverless architecture is that you reduce a lot of time spent on **VM maintenance** and **up-keep**.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform (GCP) provides multiple ways for deploying inference in the cloud. Major methods for deploying the model are:

1. Compute Engine cluster with TF serving
2. Cloud AI Platform Predictions
3. Cloud Functions

"Cloud Function" is full serverless approach and provides the following advantages:

1. Simple code for implementing the inference.
2. Great scalability, which allows you to scale from 0 to 10k.
3. Cost effective.
4. Ability to use custom versions of different frameworks (Tensorflow 2.0 or PyTorch)

The following link can be of more use if you use Tensorflow
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/how-to-serve-deep-learning-models-using-tensorflow-2-0-with-cloud-functions